# Create dataframe from Excel attachment in Outlook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, outlook

Is it possible to read an Excel file from an Outlook attachment without saving it, and return a pandas dataframe from the attached file? The file will always be in the same format.

Comment: By "saving the file", does that even mean opening the file temporarily, where it would live in the Temporary Files folder?

Comment: @BruceWayne that's a very good question. I'm actually not sure of the technicality of what happens when you use the read method of pandas, which is what I was planning on doing it with.

Comment: Attachments are MIME-encoded and have to be decoded back into the original format (which essentially means making a disk copy) for programs that are expecting that format. There's no simple way to avoid the decoding step.

Comment: @BoarGules thank you for the information. To clarify, would I be able to identify the attachment using the default outlook parameters and then access it with pandas, or does what you're saying mean that I need to actually save it first and then access it?
Edit: does what you're saying mean that when I manually double-click to open an Outlook attachment that that step is being performed?

Comment: Mail clients have the decoding built-in. You could in theory search through the attachments and find the right one. To do what you want you would have to write a decoding layer, which is not difficult, and then persuade pandas to call it, which I suspect might be very difficult, for someone not familiar with pandas internals.

Comment: @BoarGules If my lack of understanding is correctly understanding you, I'm gathering that I'm probably better off downloading and saving the attachments first and then using pandas as normal to extract and create my dataframes?

Comment: Exactly. What you want is to give pandas the identifier of the email, the name of the attachment, the details of the message store, and suitable authentication, and have pandas read the attachment directly; instead of the usual method of giving pandas the name of a file to read. While I'm sure that is possible, I am also sure it is a more ambitious project than I would want to tackle myself.

Comment: @BoarGules Thank you very much. If you will post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachments are MIME-encoded and have to be decoded back into the original format (which essentially means making a disk copy) for programs that are expecting that format.

What you want is to give pandas the identifier of the email, the name of the attachment, the details of the message store, and suitable authentication, and have pandas read the attachment directly. This would entail extending the function `pandas.read_csv()` or maybe adding a new function `read_csv_attachment()`.

While I am sure this is possible, it is a more ambitious project than I (as one unfamiliar with pandas internals) would want to tackle myself. And certainly much more work than saving the attachments manually, unless you have thousands of them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [exchangelib](https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/) to connect with Outlook and search for the attachment.

Once it is found, the attachment content can be extracted.  This will be the excel file in the form of a byte string.

The [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) method can be used to read excel files into a dataframe. This method is able to read an excel file in-memory if you provide a file-like object as an argument.

*PS pandas might not specify the `xlrd` library as a dependency and you might need to install xlrd separately to take advantage of `pandas.read_excel.*`

To convert the attachment content (byte string) to a file-like object, you can pass the byte string to `io.BytesIO`.

I was able to get this to work by emailing myself a file called `file.xls` with an email subject of `the email subject you are expecting`.  Perhaps you can adapt to your needs:

```
import io
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, DELEGATE
import pandas

# Connect to outlook (many ways to do this, take a look at exchangelib link above)
credentials = Credentials('MYWINDOMAIN\\myusername', 'mypassword')
account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address='myusername@example.com', 
    config=config,
    autodiscover=True,
    access_type=DELEGATE
)

# Find the items in the inbox matching the email subject you specify
item = account.inbox.all().get(subject='the email subject you are expecting')

# Iterate through the attachments and match with the filename you specify
# The attachment content will be the excel file in the form of a byte string
for attachment in item.attachments:
    if attachment.name == 'file.xlsx':
        my_excel_file_in_bytes = attachment.content
        break
else:
    assert False, 'No attachment with that name'

# Now that you have the excel file in bytes, convert to a file-like
# object and read the excel file in memory
my_excel_file_io = io.BytesIO(my_excel_file_in_bytes)
pandas_data_frame = pandas.read_excel(io=my_excel_file_io)
```

Comment: Thanks Liam, this is also a fantastic answer! I will give this a try and update shortly!

Comment: Worked like a charm for me, thank you! Also, I used `imaplib` and `email` instead of `exchangelib` for Gmail use case.